# Gulp task to make a release

Tags: javascript, node.js, task, gulp

I'ma newbie to Gulp. I'm trying to build a release to `dist` folder. The project structure is as follows:

```
_untitled/
 └── app/
     └── img/
     └── jade/
     └── script/
     └── style/
     └── vendor/
     └── 404.html
     └── index.html
 └── node_modules/
 └── gulpfile.js
 └── package.json
```

Here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

//-------------------- jade
gulp.task('jade', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/jade/*.jade')
    .pipe($.jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

//-------------------- style
gulp.task('style', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/style/sass/main.scss')
    .pipe($.rubySass({
        style: 'expanded',
        'sourcemap=none': true,
        noCache: true
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/style'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

//-------------------- script
gulp.task('script', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/script/**/*.js')
    .pipe($.jshint())
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter(require('jshint-stylish')))
    .pipe($.size());
});

//-------------------- htmlDist
gulp.task('htmlDist', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

//-------------------- styleDist
gulp.task('styleDist', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/style/**/*.css')
    .pipe($.concat('main.css'))
    .pipe($.csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

//-------------------- scriptDist
gulp.task('scriptDist', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/script/**/*.js')
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/script'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

//-------------------- cleanDist
gulp.task('cleanDist', function () {
    var del = require('del');
    return del('dist');
});

//-------------------- build
gulp.task('build', ['jade', 'style', 'script']);

//-------------------- buildDist
gulp.task('buildDist', ['htmlDist', 'styleDist', 'scriptDist']);

//-------------------- release
gulp.task('release', ['cleanDist', 'build', 'buildDist']);
```

With this, when I type `gulp release` I have an ok `dist` folder, except that `index.html` is empty and `0 KB` size. And then, when I try to make `gulp release` once again (in second time, with `dist` folder already existed), I have only `404.html` file in `dist` folder and an error with following output:

```
gulp release
[02:36:14] Using gulpfile D:\Coding\_untitled\gulpfile.js
[02:36:14] Starting 'cleanDist'...
[02:36:14] Finished 'cleanDist' after 52 ms
[02:36:14] Starting 'jade'...
[02:36:15] Starting 'style'...
[02:36:16] Starting 'script'...
[02:36:17] Starting 'htmlDist'...
[02:36:17] Starting 'styleDist'...
[02:36:17] Starting 'scriptDist'...
[02:36:17] all files 38 B
[02:36:17] Finished 'script' after 1.19 s
[02:36:17] all files 432 B
[02:36:17] Finished 'jade' after 2.88 s

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: ENOENT, chmod 'D:\Coding\_untitled\dist\script\main.js'
```

After all of this, if I try to make `gulp release` (that would be in third), `dist` folder doesn't even appear. Looks like this task runs great (not counting empty `index.html`) when `dist` folder doesn't exist, and then it just goes wrong. Well I need to get this task to delete an entire `dist` folder first, and then build a release. Running `gulp buildDist` separately works correct (`index.html` is normal).

This is my first post, i've tried my best to get it right. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify dependencies in gulp, they are run **in parallel**, not in sequence. This means that your `jade`, `style`, and `script` tasks are running **at the same time** as your `htmlDist`, `styleDist`, and `scriptDist` tasks.

You should use the [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.org/package/run-sequence) package to ensure that your tasks run in order.

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence('cleanDist', 'build', 'buildDist', callback);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Gulp documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support), you don't need any third part package,

just create dependent tasks :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// takes in a callback so the engine knows when it'll be done
gulp.task('one', function(cb) {
    // do stuff -- async or otherwise
    cb(err); // if err is not null and not undefined, the run will stop, and note that it failed
});

// identifies a dependent task must be complete before this one begins
gulp.task('two', ['one'], function() {
    // task 'one' is done now
});

gulp.task('default', ['one', 'two']);
```